# Ansible throws an “ ERROR! A worker was found in a dead state ” error

Tags: memory, ansible, automation, swap, oom

When I run a playbook that simply copies a directory from one place to another, ansible throws

> ERROR! A worker was found in a dead state

Error. After some googling, it looks like this is caused by the oom-killer killing the ansible process (but i'm not exactly sure that this is the case). My Memory is:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            991         372         448           1         170         467
Swap:           511         365         146
```

I don't have a clue how to fix it. I should mention I only had the RAM when I first executed the playbook, which couldn't run cause of low memory. After that, I added the swap.Not sure if it's related but note that it's a [swap file](https://www.centos.org/docs//5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-swap-creating-file.html), not a separate partition.

I've watched the memory while running and I see that the free swap goes down very fast once it runs that task. The error message is thrown when it hits 0.

---

I'm running the following playbook.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root

  vars:
    portals:
      - mysite
    contentPath: "/var/www/"
    backupPath: "/home/dataFiles/backups/"

  tasks:

    - name: backup content
      copy:
        src: "{{ contentPath }}/{{ item }}"
        dest: "{{backupPath}}/{{ item }}/{{ ansible_date_time.date }}/"
      with_items:
        - "{{ portals }}"
...
```

The error I've given above is the only info I get out of ansible. Even running the playbook verbosely doesn't give anything additional for that.

Comment: Update: added 2 GB of swap. It still runs out when the command is run.

Comment: You should add the task which throws the error and the complete error message returned by Ansible.

Comment: @HenrikPingel Thanks for the response. Added the info.

Comment: Look on your logs. Read up on [ansible debugging](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ansible+debugging). Pfovide more information.

Comment: Yes, you need to run your `ansible-playbook` command with `-vvv`. You should also add your ansible version with `ansible --verison`

Comment: If there are many files under `portals` you might want to check if the [synchronize](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html) module works better for you. Its a wrapper around rsync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a note in the [copy_module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) documentation:

> The “copy” module recursively copy facility does not scale to lots (>hundreds) of files. For alternative, see synchronize module, which is a wrapper around rsync.

Assuming this is the case here one should consider using the [synchronize](https://docs.ansible.com/archive/ansible/2.3/synchronize_module.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

This solved my issue:

```
export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works for me:

`env no_proxy='*' ansible-playbook collect-facts.yml`

You can also add `export no_proxy="*"` to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`, so you don't need to type it every time.

More detail on this : https://www.whatan00b.com/posts/debugging-a-segfault-from-ansible/

(Credit: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/32554#issuecomment-572985680)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The relationship with the question is unclear. A segfault is not an oom-killer event.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but I was not using the copy module in any task.

In my case the problem was that the machine (on which was running the ansible task when the error appeared) was run out of memory.

I checked it out by launching the playbook and then in another terminal launching `htop` and monitoring how the RAM and the SWAP were filling up as the execution of the playbook was going on.

I solved it by increasing the RAM of the machine which was failing.

(Increasing the SWAP would not be so effective since it is not a random access memory but disk memory, so the "computational power" given by 1GB of SWAP is way less thant the one given by 1GB of RAM.)